# Change Elastic Beanstalk application IIS bindings

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application deployed under an Elastic Beanstalk environment. The EB environment platform is .NET/IIS. 
I am looking for a way to change IIS web site bindings without using a remote desktop connection.
I think this should be possible through configuration files (ebextensions) or through the AWS CLI. However, I'm not able to find any documentation on this.
Is this possible at all and could somebody give the way to do it?

Thank you!